# Change in Pam configuration

Tags: linux, rhel, login, pam

I have change the password policy to apply the same for root  by "enforce_for_root" and for now it apply the password complexity on root yet after removing the "enforce_for_root" still applying the complexity on root user

**Before:**

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so enforce_for_root try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
```

**After :**

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
```

I don't understand why still applying enforce for root while the definition removed also I tried to restart sshd but still not working to revert back the old method

Comment: IIRC root can still set whatever password it wants, but the OS will just complain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RHEL, you should use `authconfig`, as stated by the [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/pam_configuration_files). That being said, you could try

```
sudo /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update
```

And reboot to see if that solves your issue.